# Highlight in red all cells that have a formula with a mixed reference

Tags: excel, excel-2010

The VBA code I have at the moment also paints red all cells with absolute references (e.g.: `=$A$1+A$2`) and that's where it doesn't meet what I need at the moment.
I need only the cells in which at least one of the formulas have a mixed reference (e.g.: `=$A$1+$A2`) or only a mixed reference (e.g.: `=$A1+A$2`) to be colored red.

VBA code:

```
Sub test2()
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range

Worksheets("Plan1k").Activate
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
With r
.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With
For Each c In r
 If InStr(c.Formula, "$") > 0 Then
  c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the Regular Expression assembly, you have to reference it.

```vb
Sub test2()
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
  Dim RegEx As RegExp
  Set RegEx = New RegExp
  RegEx.Pattern = "(([^\x24]|^)[a-zA-Z]+\x24\d+)|(\x24[a-zA-Z]+\d+)"
  RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
  RegEx.Global = False
Worksheets("Plan1k").Activate
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
With r
.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With
For Each c In r
  Set res = RegEx.Execute(c.Formula)
  If res.Count > 0 Then c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
  'If InStr(c.Formula, "$") > 0 Then
  
  'End If
Next c
End Sub
```

The result of sample test:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!!! It fully met my expectations.
Solved!